# Capture target strings with optional line breaks in them using regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel, pcre

I have the following regex to capture translation strings in a laravel project:

```
(trans|trans_choice|Lang::get|Lang::choice|Lang::trans|Lang::transChoice|@lang|@choice)\(([\'"]([\/a-zA-Z0-9_-]+([.][^)\'"]+?)+)[\'"])(\s?.*,\s?.*)*?[\)\]];?
```

The regex will happily capture:

```
@lang('validation.invalid')
@lang('validation.invalid', ['field' => $field])
```

However, the moment I introduce a line break

```
@lang('validation.invalid', [
'field' => $field
])
```

or a couple in between:

```
@lang('validation.invalid', [
'field' => $field,

'message' => $error->getMessage()
])
```

It no longer targets the string

Comment: Replace `(.*,\s?.*)*?` with `.*?` and prepend the pattern with `(?s)`

Comment: It captures string with optional line breaks fine, however, now it does not catch the final enclosing parentheses

Comment: Yeah, that is context dependent. I suspect you want to match them at the end of a line, thus try `(?sm)(trans|trans_choice|Lang::get|Lang::choice|Lang::trans|Lang::transChoice|@lang|@choice)\(([\'"]([\/a-zA-Z0-9_-]+([.][^)\'"]+?)+)[\'"]).*?[)\]];?$`. Or `(?sm)(trans|trans_choice|Lang::get|Lang::choice|Lang::trans|Lang::transChoice|@lang|@choice)\(([\'"]([\/a-zA-Z0-9_-]+([.][^)\'"]+?)+)[\'"])(.*?)[)\]];?$(?<!\(\))`. See https://regex101.com/r/uXcC5d/1